# How to redirect to the web another web page by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Bootstrap, CSS, HTML, JavaScript/jQuery for designing my project. I have used some jQuery plugin in my project hence my button & `<a>` tag are not working. When I click on it doesn't redirect me to my webpage. How can I reactivate all `<a>` tag & button from a webpage using jQuery.

```html
<a href="http://www.mahacareermitra.in/" target="_blank">Access the portal</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what plugin you have activated: try disabling the one by one.

Probably one of them ( or your code ) is listening to the click event on the links and preventing the event.

Something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   .... // more code
} )
```

In that case you should listen to more specific tags (like, using a class to identify them) and leave the general behaviour for link unaltered.

Comment: yes but if i want to write my own js to redirect all a tag how can i do this?

Comment: You should really dig into jquery event listener documentation I suppose :) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `window.location` "href" property, or "replace" method:

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) reference

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply redirect using jQuery

jQuery is not necessary, and window.location.replace(...) will best simulate an HTTP redirect.

window.location.replace(...) is better than using window.location.href, because replace() does not keep the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco.

If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, use  location.href

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use location.replace

**For example:**

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Comment: look at this link for reference :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery hope you will get the answer.....